# Domain mapping the top-level site in wordpress multi

Tags: domain-mapping

I'm using donncha's WordPress MU Domain Mapping. But I noticed that it doesn't allow to domain map the top level site. Blog id 1, all other blog id's works fine to map.

Is there a work around without moving the top blog to a subdomain blog? Needs to be a permanent redirect (301).

I'm using cpanel as hosting management.

Big thanks!

Dennis, Norway

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact answer but maybe you will find it handy:

- [Change the Primary Domain for a WordPress Multi-Site Network](http://www.wordpress-website.org/change-primary-domain-wordpress-multisite-network/)
- [How to map domains to sites within WordPress multisite](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-map-domains-with-wordpress-multisite)

Comment: Hi JohnnyPea.. sorry for my late answer. I found the solution by just trying to change the blogid in mysql. And it worked. But the plugins doesnt allow to domain map blogid 1. thanks anyway!